# Can't install precompiled clang on raspbian correctly

Tags: linux, installation, clang, raspbian

I'm using raspberry pi3, here's the information of my system:

> Linux raspberry 4.9.37-v7+ #1017 SMP Thu Jul 13  11:26:04 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

I downloaded clang+llvm-5.0.0-armv7a-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz using wget from [here](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html), then I decompressed it using tar `xf` and copied the whole directory I got from `tar` into `/usr/local/`.

But when I was trying to run clang, I got the following message:

> pi@raspberry:/usr/local/clang+llvm-5.0.0-armv7a-linux-gnueabihf/bin$ ./clang
>
> ./clang: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by ./clang)
>
> ./clang: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./clang)
>
> pi@raspberry:/usr/local/clang+llvm-5.0.0-armv7a-linux-gnueabihf/bin$ ./clang++
>
> ./clang++: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by ./clang++)
>
> ./clang++: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./clang++)
>
> pi@raspberry:/usr/local/clang+llvm-5.0.0-armv7a-linux-gnueabihf/bin$ ./clang-5.0
>
> ./clang-5.0: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by ./clang-5.0)
>
> ./clang-5.0: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./clang-5.0)

My clang-3.5.0-10+rpi1, which was installed by `apt-get`, works well on my system.

What can I do to fix these problems?

Comment: Install newer glibc and libtinfo as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need newer libs glibc and libtinfo.

Just run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to upgrade all libraries

Comment: I tried your method, but my glibc version is still 2.19, it ddn't change. I still can't use clang-5.0

Comment: Then you need to update to newer versions of libstdc++ and libtinfo. You can: compile them yourself, find a repository with new versions and add them to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or (recommended) compile clang5.0 yourself